# Robots Text Blocked

Tags: php, robots.txt

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {
echo "User-agent: *\n" ;
echo "Disallow: /\n" ;
} else {
echo "User-agent: *\n" ;
echo "Disallow: \n" ;
}
```

What does this code do in robots.php?

I found it on my server and it seems to block text from being indexed by the search engines

Comment: This does not seem to do too much.   It is a php file that responses as if it were a robots.txt file, setting up constraints .. User-agen:* and Disallow: /.   This sets up to prevent anyone on port 443 to access your root directory.

Comment: http://www.inkplant.com/code/https-robots.php

Answer (score 0):

When you read that page on port 443 (usually reserved for secure connection) e.g. **https**://yoursite.com/robots.php, returned content will be as follows:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

The "User-agent: *" means this section applies to all robots. The "Disallow: /" tells the robot that it should not visit any pages on the site.

Otherwise (page `robots.php` visited on any other port - **http**://yoursite.com/robots.php) returned content will be as follows:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

In this case robot can visit any page on the site.

Also `header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");` displays a page content as regular plain text.